# Windows 7 RTM: Loopback SMB over TCP/IPv6 connection preventing sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, power-management, ipv6, smb

I'm running Windows 7 RTM with homegroup, network discovery, file and printer sharing, public folder, media streaming and Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service all turned off, but the computer still doesn't go to sleep. `powercfg -requests` shows this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
An active remote client has recently sent requests to this machine.

AWAYMODE:
None.
```

Running `ipconfig /release` doesn't help, and `netstat -n -o -b` shows this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netstat -n -o -b

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        127.0.0.1:49179        ESTABLISHED     1616
 [AppleMobileDeviceService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        127.0.0.1:49181        ESTABLISHED     1616
 [AppleMobileDeviceService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49179        127.0.0.1:27015        ESTABLISHED     3976
 [iTunesHelper.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49181        127.0.0.1:27015        ESTABLISHED     3976
 [iTunesHelper.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49209        127.0.0.1:27015        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49555        127.0.0.1:27015        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    [fe80::9075:f418:87dd:8288%11]:445  [fe80::9075:f418:87dd:8288%11]:49202  ESTABLISHED     4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [fe80::9075:f418:87dd:8288%11]:49202  [fe80::9075:f418:87dd:8288%11]:445  ESTABLISHED     4
 Can not obtain ownership information
```

What *is* `\FileSystem\srvnet` anyway, and how can I allow my computer to go to sleep automatically?

Disabling Wake-On-LAN from device manager didn't change anything, but disabling the network adapter and then re-enabling it did. The SMB over TCP/IPv6 link-local connection at the end vanished, and `powercfg -requests` showed no issues preventing sleep mode. Unfortunately, after a few moments the connection pair reappeared, this time using the IPv6 loopback address:

```
  TCP    [::1]:445              [::1]:49401            ESTABLISHED     4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::1]:49401            [::1]:445              ESTABLISHED     4
 Can not obtain ownership information
```

Now disabling the network adapter doesn't help anymore, but stopping the Workstation service did. Why would the system establish an SMB connection to itself?

Answer (score 1):

Srvnet is the "server network driver". This is likely your NIC having the Wake On LAN issue just like Vista.

- Go to **Network Connections**
- Right click your Local Area Ethernet adapter and hit properties
- Open the **power management** tab, and uncheck "allow this device to wake the computer"
- apply & OK

[image]